# How to install WebLogic on a machine where there is already a Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm installing for the first time Weblogic:

- Url: **https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-main-097127.html**
- Installer type: **Generic Installer for Oracle WebLogic Server and Oracle Coherence**

As you can see from the image
[image]

the installer states that is going to create a **new Oracle home**.

I remember that when I installed **Oracle Database** I read, during the installation, that the installer was creating a **Oracle Home**.

My question may seem pretty stupid:
can I launch the default installation for Weblogic or it can create problem since there is already Oracle Database installed and a Oracle home already exists?

Thank you

Comment: As far as I can tell, you should install each Oracle software product into its own directory (i.e. *Oracle Home*). Both database and weblogic (or, previously, IAS) can be on the same machine. Note that, if there are many users that access it, response might suffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install every oracle product in a different home directory.
You can set the home directory in the installation wizard.